# Finetuning text-to-equation vertical spacing on standard vs. tall equations

Tags: equations, vertical-spacing

I am struggling with spacing before an equation.  I want my equation to be plain like-next-line continuations, as shown in the following:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\showoutput
 
\begin{document}

\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{1pt plus 1pt minus 1pt}
\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{1pt plus 1pt minus 1pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{1ex}

My first(a) paragraph just uses the standard latex equation environment. My first(b) paragraph just uses the standard latex equation environment.
\[  C_{X} = \text{Cash Return at Time 1} = \$12 \;,\]
The first(c) paragraph should be very tightly knit indeed.

My second(a) paragraph just uses the standard latex equation environment with a fraction. My second(b) paragraph just uses 
\[  C_{Y} = \frac{\text{Cash Return at Time 1}}{\$12} \;,\]
The second(c) paragraph should be very tightly knit indeed.

\end{document}
```

[image: short text paragraph with equations]

The `\showoutput` tells me that the first equation has a `...\glue(\baselineskip) 2.488`, while the second only has a `...\glue(\lineskip) 1.0`.  As a consequence, the first equation has the spacing I want (i.e., as if the math is just another text line [though I may give it another point or two]), while the second is too tight on the preceding text.

How would I instruct latex to always get the same spacing from text to equation in both paragraphs (i.e., both types of equations)?

Comment: define "same" the  baseline to baseline space of the second is necessarily larger than in the first to make space for the fraction

Comment: somehow I need to push down the baseline of the fraction so that the distance to the preceding text on the top of the equation is the same.  I don't want the baseline per se to be the same...I want the distance to the top of the equation be the same.

Comment: tex does not track the baselines of individual subterms once added to the formula the fraction is an opaque box

Comment: thx, D.  I would think I am not the only one who would love to get constant spacing between the bottom of preceding text and the top of a following equation within a paragraph.  I can work around this by hand-tuning, though...